# What is the easiest way to play a sound sample in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, audio

I'm toying around with constructing a basic music composition system for fun. I can represent music in memory, but I'd (obviously) like to be able to output actual sounds! I don't really care what the format is (MIDI, mp3, ogg, whatever). I just want to be able to load samples into the program and play them in the simplest way possible. I've searched around for a solution but everything I'm seeing is either a) too complex (overhead-wise) for my needs, b) not actively supported, or c) not well-documented. I would love to see an example of sound output or otherwise, some direction on the simplest way to do so.

Comment: MIDI is not an audio format.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Not really a helpful comment, if I could read in MIDI data and play it back, that would be fine with me.

Comment: If you're on linux or osx, the simplest way is to load a soundfile into memory (probably using `libsndfile`) and write it out to `/dev/audio`.  Or shell out to `sox` or similar and have that play an audio file.

Comment: @BenjaminKovach: the comment about MIDI is very relevant.  It's not entirely clear what you need here.  If all you want to do is play pre-existing sound files, people should suggest something very different from if you want to play MIDI files, or if you want to render audio based upon your composition system.

Comment: @JohnL MIDI is fine; I just need to be able to play sound samples. I actually found a way to it (on OSX) in a relatively lightweight way, which I'll post here later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using MIDI and sending events to SimpleSynth, on Mac OSX. This was achieved using the [hmidi](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmidi) package and [the bindings to OSX's CoreMIDI by bkomuves](http://code.haskell.org/~bkomuves/projects/macosx-core/dist/doc/html/macosx-core/System-MacOSX-CoreMIDI.html). I had to install a fork of the hmidi package from [here](https://github.com/sixohsix/hmidi) to get it working with the latest GHC. I then installed [SimpleSynth](http://notahat.com/simplesynth/) and enabled an IAC Driver using the [Audio MIDI Setup](https://sites.google.com/site/mfalab/mac-stuff/how-to-use-the-iac-driver) utility on OSX. I then set SimpleSynth to listen from the IAC Driver I set up and was able to use the `enumerateDestinations` function from bkomuvres' bindings to CoreMIDI to grab the first available `Destination` and send `MidiEvents` from `hmidi` using `send`. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You might like [Euterpea](http://euterpea.com/), which isn't on Hackage but was a breeze to install and has quite verbose documentation (it seems it forms the core of an introductory Haskell course at Yale). Hover over the word "Euterpea" in the menu at the top to find more links/instructions.

Comment: This wasn't the solution I ended up using, but it led me to it, so thank you!

Comment: @BenjaminKovach do you possibly remember what your solution was? I had a look through the docs but can't seem to find any way to actually play audio, only the ability to render to a wav file.

Comment: @Chris Take a look at the answer he helpfully wrote up below!

Comment: This link is unfortunately now dead

Comment: @Qqwy Luckily "Euterpea" is such a unique word that every search engine returns loads of relevant results. Never mind, I've updated the link anyway.

Answer (score 0):

With Haskell, you may wish to get a handle on the language fully by utilising other libraries/applications from your code, however the following link is a link to libraries for music and sound.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Music_and_sound

Another idea is to gain familiarity with OpenAL with C/C++ and then from there you will have some familiarity with the structure of HOpenAL (Haskell binding of OpenAL which indeed calls the OpenAL DLL/SO).

Link with straightforward tutorial for OpenAL ago!
http://enigma-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=730.0;wap2

I hope this helps...