# Is it possible to play an audio file from a cross-platform Haskell program without any external tools?

Tags: haskell, audio

I want to write a metronome program in Haskell. I got the easiest part right: ticking at a given BPM and outputting "downbeat" or "upbeat" accordingly. I have also got audio files of downbeat and upbeat ticks in WAV format, but I would not mind converting them if necessary.

I have read some SO questions:
[Play a wav file with Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14005592), [How to play an audio file from Haskell code, cross-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29841999), [What is the easiest way to play a sound sample in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23411493), [Sound lib haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9764248)

The first and the second ones does not meet my needs because I need to install sdl libs on my computer for [SDL](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL) and [SDL-mixer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL-mixer) packages to work. Also, it is quite a pain to do this on Windows.

The third one did not help me because it only works with MIDIs or custom Euterpea format and I wanted to play a sound effect, not music.

The fourth one is again about the haskell binding to an external library.

So, how do I play these files from a Haskell program without using any external libraries (and possibly packages)? I would also like the answer to be cross-platform, but POSIX-only and Windows only answers are good too.

Comment: I would be surprised if this were possible without a very large amount of work.  If you're not depending on an external library, you have to rewrite the external library, and that's usually a major task.

Comment: Actually there is a very easy way to play audio without any libraries, especially if it doesn't need to be high quality: generate a stream of numbers to STDOUT and pipe that to a program like `aplay`. Not sure if that's also as easy on Windows as it is on Linux. Cf. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11463/mozart-golf-mini-rondo/11514

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thank you for the idea. Do you know if it is possible to make aplay start playing the file and then just leave without waiting for it to end?

edit: `aplay filename &` helped

Comment: also are there any windows only ways?

Comment: This might not be helpful, but I use `ghcjs` and wrote a small `Tone.js` binding for [an ear training game](https://luqui.github.io/practice-tools/ear-training.html) I made ([source](https://github.com/luqui/practice-tools/tree/483cb1b6b60f05c455c698d9c031dbfb8d9961da)).  It works nicely, though ghcjs was quite a challenge to install (this was a couple years ago).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
putStrLn "upbeat"
```

consider:

```
forkIO (callProcess "mpv" ["upbeat.mp3"])
```

(Or use whatever media player you prefer over `mpv`.)
You can read the docs for more info about [`forkIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkIO) and [`callProcess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.17.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:callProcess) and for suggestions for more robust alternatives if the time ever comes to graduate from prototype to serious program. Don't forget to pass `-threaded` when building your executable to get the threaded runtime system; this will make your inter-`callProcess` delays significantly more reliable.

Comment: I have used `callProcess "player upbeat.mp3 &"` before so the process starts and does not wait for the file to end. `&` is only available on POSIX shell and I thought that forkIO will do that. It does not; it waits for the process to exit. How do I do the same thing with forkIO or some other related command?

Comment: upd: I found the way; it is spawnProcess. mpv outputs a lot of things into stdout though, how do I silence it?

Comment: This seems like it might delay the timing a little bit because it's starting a whole process to play the tick sound

Comment: @LevZagatov `forkIO` should indeed return before `callProcess` does, and in my tests it does. Can you put together a minimal reproducible example in a new question showing how you are determining that it does not do that for you? On silencing `mpv`... well, read through the `System.Process` docs I linked for more on how to control where the process' stdout (and friends) go.

Comment: @user253751 Yep. Fingers crossed the delay is about the same on each process start, so that the rhythm at least is even.

Comment: @DanielWagner Problem is the delay is not even. Audio files have different length. Another issue I have found: if mpv is used and you do some things while the app is running in the background the sound will horribly delay on every key press and mouse click.

Comment: Minimal reproducible example here. code: https://pastebin.com/147rH3MN files are downloadable from links in comments

Comment: Note: try leaving this example running for 30 seconds and see if bpm is exactly 120 (two ticks per second) after that

Comment: @LevZagatov `500` is way too short. For 120bpm, you want `500000` (=1000000 microseconds/second * 60seconds/minute / 120beats/minute). It doesn't work well with the non-threaded runtime, but it works well for me indefinitely when compiled with `-threaded`. I have added a comment about this to my answer.